# Agrupar datos por semana

Tags: sql-server, date, lógica

Hice el siguiente ejemplo que aplicaria para la lógica de algo mayor:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Data')   IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Data     END

SET DATEFIRST 1;

CREATE TABLE #Data(
    [Date]  DATE,
    [Num]   INT
)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ('2020-05-27',1),
       ('2020-05-29',2),
       ('2020-05-31',3),
       ('2020-05-31',4),
       ('2020-06-01',5),
       ('2020-06-02',6)

SELECT MIN([Date]) AS [Date],[Suma] = SUM([Num])
FROM #Data
GROUP BY DATEPART(Wk,[DATE])
ORDER BY 1
```

Lo cual tiene como resultado

```
Date        | Suma
------------------
2020-05-27  | 10
2020-06-01  | 11
```

Pero busco algo que retorne el primer lunes de esa semana, que es este caso seria algo asi:

```
Date        | Suma
------------------
2020-05-25  | 10
2020-06-01  | 11
```

En un principio parecía lógico, no se si alguien podria ayudarme con esto, Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función datePart con el parámetro WeekDay para saber el día de la semana.

[DatePart](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Es importante establecer, cuál es el primer día con Set dateFirst

[Set DateFirst](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Una solución puede ser:

set dateFirst 1
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Data')   IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Data     END

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

CREATE TABLE #Data(
    [Date]  DATE,
    [Num]   INT
)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES ('2020-05-27',1),
       ('2020-05-29',2),
       ('2020-05-31',3),
       ('2020-05-31',4),
       ('2020-06-01',5),
       ('2020-06-02',6);

With myDays As (SELECT MIN([Date]) AS [Date],[Suma] = SUM([Num])
FROM #Data
GROUP BY DATEPART(Wk,[DATE])
), FirstDays As
(
    select m.Date, m.Suma, dateadd(day,((-(datepart(weekday,m.date)))+1),m.Date) as FirstDayOfWeek 
    from myDays m
)
select * from FirstDays
```

Con el resultado obtenido por tu query, buscamos el primer día de la semana, restando los 
días de diferencia del día de la semana en que estás, más 1. Si estamos en lunes, primer día de la semana, sumamos a la fecha -1 +1. Si estuviésemos a miércoles. -3 + 1 Total miércoles menos dos días.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Un muy buen uso de CTE, muy adecuado, ¡Gracias!